# Fragments Failed to inflate

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm a little shakey on this so bear with me.  I'm trying to teach myself and I'm currently working out of the WROX Android 4 Application Development for Beginners book. I'm currently on the section "Communication between fragments" and I feel like I'm getting it, but when I run the code taken right out of the book, I get "failed to inflate" in the logcat.  Here's the XMLs followed by the .java files, then the error.  I can't figure out what's killing this:

main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.Fragments.Fragment1"
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.Fragments.Fragment2"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lblFragment1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is fragment #1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFE00"
    >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is fragment #2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGetText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get text in Fragment #1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentsActivity.java:

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FragmentsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Fragment1.java:

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ---Inflate the layout for this fragment---
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }

}
```

Fragment2.java:

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //---Inflate the layout for this fragment---
        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //---Button View---
        Button btnGetText = (Button)
                getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnGetText);
        btnGetText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView lbl = (TextView)
                        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lblFragment1);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), lbl.getText(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523): Failed to inflate
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:282)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at com.example.fragments.FragmentsActivity.onCreate(FragmentsActivity.java:15)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.Fragments.Fragment1: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     ... 21 more
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.Fragments.Fragment1" on path: /data/app/com.example.fragments-2.apk
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
04-20 15:09:55.759: E/ActivityThread(9523):     ... 24 more
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace from LogCat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the Layout definition is wrong `android:name="com.example.Fragments.Fragment1"`. It should be

```
android:name="com.example.fragments.Fragment1"
```

the same for `Fragment2`

Comment: *smacks head against wall*

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you mistyped the package name.

Logcat shows that it can't find the class `com.example.Fragments.Fragment1`. Your source code for `Fragment1` shows that you named the package `com.example.fragments` instead of `com.example.Fragments`. Capitalize the package name, or lowercase the references to it.